How do I input box-drawing characters?
I'm writing something where I want to show lsblk output, such as
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0  1.2T  0 disk  
├─sda1        8:1    0    5G  0 part  
└─sda2        8:2    0  1.2T  0 part  

You'll note the ├, ─, and └ characters. I've currently got
\begin{verbatim}
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0  1.2T  0 disk  
├─sda1        8:1    0    5G  0 part  
└─sda2        8:2    0  1.2T  0 part  
\end{verbatim}

However this compiles to display as the following:

I am using \UseRawInputEncoding and usepackage[T1]{fontenc}.
How can I get these characters to display correctly inside a verbatim or verbatim-like environment?

never use \UseRawInputEncoding as you see that (by design) breaks all of latex's support for non ascii characters. It is just for use for some very special legacy codes that need to install their own encoding support so need the standard latex encoding mechanism disabled first.

You want \usepackage{pmboxdraw}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\begin{document}


\begin{verbatim}
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0  1.2T  0 disk  
├─sda1        8:1    0    5G  0 part  
└─sda2        8:2    0  1.2T  0 part  
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}


